# android-start a new line between to radio button

Tags: android

I try to start a new line where the comment "here". All I try didn't succeed.
I can't just choose "android:orientation="horizontal" because I have another component and it doesn't work well.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo" >


 <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/radio_hot_or_cold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="14.5sp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"  //not good
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup_consume"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radio_consume"
            android:orientation="horizontal"  //not good >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_message_hot"
                android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:minEms="2"
                android:minWidth="15sp" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView android:text="צריכה בחום" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="" />

    //////////////here I want a new line

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_message_cold"
                android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:minEms="2"
                android:minWidth="15sp" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView android:text="צריכה בקור" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </TableRow>

................

</TableLayout>
```

I can't just choose "android:orientation="horizontal" because I have another component and it doesn't work well.

Comment: what do you mean by new line, horizontal delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:paddingTop="##dp"` to your `EditText` or `android:paddingBottom="##dp"` to your `RadioButton`.

Edit: What about doing this:

```
<RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="" />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_message_cold"
            android:layout_marginRight="10.5sp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:minEms="2"
            android:minWidth="15sp" >
        </EditText>

        <TextView android:text="צריכה בקור" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </RadioGroup>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: what did you fill in for "##"?

Comment: Also, what exactly to you mean by new line? Just a space or as Marko asked, a delimiter? A new TableRow maybe?

Comment: If I understand you, you mean to add tableRaw between the 2 radio button. I tried this. This is not good because it refer to each one a a group (instead of group of 2 button..)

Comment: Does this have to be a table layout? could you use a relative layout maybe and position the objects using that?